# Git colors: How do I set colors for the upstream branch in “git branch -vv”?

Tags: git, colors, git-config

I'm able to see my local and remote branches colored differently with the following configuration in my .gitconfig.

```
[color "branch"]
    current = bold cyan
    local = normal
    remote = bold red
```

In `git branch -vv` however, there is an additional upstream branch displayed that has a different color which is unreadable on my screen.

How do I configure this “upstream” color? (movie pun unintended :)

A `git help config` lists the color parameters for many branch types but I'm not able to find out one for this upstream branch.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Looking at the source code, you want to use `upstream` as the slot name:

```
[color "branch"]
    upstream = bold blue
```

It looks like more up-to-date man pages also have the option listed.  The ones you were looking at are probably older than 1.8.3 (which is when the feature first appeared).

Comment: I was able to find the updated reference here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/config.txt

Where did you find the upstream color reference? Which specific file I mean? Just curious.

Comment: I found the reference to it here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/branch.c#L77