# How can I soften the colorization in git's listing of branches?

Tags: git, shell, ls, colorize

If you run

```
git branch --list -vv
```

I get something like:

```
  foo-develop               8d5a0f30 [blazingdb/develop] [develop] unit test for bar_reader
* branch-0.5                81324bcb [joeuser/branch-0.5] Merge pull request #123 from somerepo/some-feature-branch-name
```

... with the current branch name highlighted in green and the remote branch names and origins, in the square brackets, are highlighted in blue. This is fine by me - almost. The blue color is rather dark and has poor contrast against my black terminal background. This, while my `ls` output is colorized with a softer shade of blue.

My questions:

1. How do I change the colors git uses for this (and perhaps other) colorizations?
2. Suppose that for `ls` the coloring diverges only slightly from the "harsher" defaults - so we get more pastel-like reds, greens, and blues. Is there a way to make git "use the color variants from LS" - dynamically or statically? (I have my `LS_COLORS` set somehow, so maybe through that).

Note: I've [read](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) that you can make configuration settings such as

```
git config --global color.diff.meta "white bold"
```

to set specific colors. So the answer to (1.) might be as simple as telling me which config settings correspond to branch listing colors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git colors: How do I set colors for the upstream branch in “git branch -vv”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012738/git-colors-how-do-i-set-colors-for-the-upstream-branch-in-git-branch-vv)

Comment: See details on what colours you can set in e.g. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-colorbranchltslotgt

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Almost a dupe. There's the question of the terminal's "own" colors vs ls' colors vs what git uses.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't ask two questions at once!

Comment: Please edit your question and split it into two.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to Question (1.):

The relevant git configuration key is `color.branch.upstream` (*not* `color.branch.remote` nor `color.decorate.branch` etc.). By default, it is set to `blue`, which on your terminal apparently has unsatisfactory contrast with the background. Consider changing it to "blue bold":

```
git config --global color.branch.upstream "blue bold"
```